# Why does ten times ten give a zero in jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

10 times 10 gives 0 in python jupyter notebook.

Tried executing the code on Jupyter notebook.

```
10 ^ 10
```

Comment: Unclear on what you are asking about

Comment: Shouldn't there be a difference between `10 * 10` and `10 ^ 10`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `^` is the `XOR` operator in python. The `power` operator is `**`. So the correct syntax would be:

```
10**10
```